# When is the best time of year to install a fence?

Tags: wood, fence

Is there any right time to put the fence up in the backyard considering you have saved enough $$$s? Looking at the winter season we have and snow in coming months, is this the right time or should i wait until spring?

P.S.: I am not gonna do it by myself. I am gonna hire some professional fence company.

Comment: If someone else is doing it, the right time is to do it when you have the money. If you are doing it, the right time to do it is when it's not freezing outside.

Comment: I prefer summer. One or two posts and a beer.  one or two more posts, another beer.  Get the pattern here?

Comment: @shirlockhomes That method usually means you get about 10-12 posts in before you completely skip step 1.

Comment: @Tester:  you can't rush a good fence in the summer time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on where you live. The best results are when the ground is dry. Frozen ground, spring mud season etc are bad times as you cannot set the posts soundly and you may see some settling later on.  Summer and early fall are great times to build a fence. See my earlier "beer" comment.

Comment: Time for a break, it's beer-o'clock

Comment: This reminds me of Dave from Dave's Farm. He would estimate all of his jobs in how many beers he would need to drink. "That's a 3 beer job."

Answer (score 4):

It will be easier (i.e. cheaper) when the ground is not frozen and it's not too muddy. Snow will also cause a little extra labor. The fence company will be busier in the Spring, so that might make it cheaper in the off season.